# In jersey async client, how to wait for all the call to complete and then execute some code

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, jersey-client, task-queue

I am using jersey-client - 2.26 to make an HTTP call.
I am making the async call using the "async()" method.

I loop through my list and make multiple async calls.
Due to this "async" call, it does not wait for the response of the call and go to the next iteration and initiate another call.
Now if the loop executes for 10 times, it will make 10 calls, now initiating this call is correct in loop, but I want to wait for the responses fo the all 10 calls and then want to execute some other code.

```
private Client getClient() {
        SslConfigurator sslConfig = SslConfigurator.newInstance().trustStoreFile(keyStorePath)
                .trustStorePassword(keyStorePassword).keyStoreFile(keyStorePath).keyPassword(keyStorePassword);

        SSLContext sslContext = sslConfig.createSSLContext();

        final Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(sslContext)
                .hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                        if (hostname.equals("localhost")) {
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }).build();
        return client;
    }
==================================================================
javax.ws.rs.client.Client client = getClient();
for (BPMInput bpmInputObje : bpmInputList) {
     WebTarget wt = client.target(BPM_PROCESS_URL + "?tenantId=" + reqInput.getTenantId());
                    System.out.println("Async call is started.");

                    Builder builder = wt.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

                    /* this function will set header parameters in new HTTP call */
                    setHeaderParametersForAsyncCall(reqInput, builder);
    // ******** now call the async call ************
      builder.async().post(Entity.json(payload), new InvocationCallback() {

            @Override
            public void completed(Object obj) {
                try {
                    BPMResponse bpmResponse = mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(obj), BPMResponse.class);
                    System.out.println("Async call after completion forward navigation : "
                            + bpmResponse.getNavigation().getForward().toString());
                    System.out.println("Async call after completion backword navigation : "
                            + bpmResponse.getNavigation().getBackward().toString());
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void failed(Throwable arg0) {
                System.out.println("Async call is failed : " + arg0);
            }
        });

}
 // Now after this, all calls get initiated, I want to wait for the response 
 // of these all calls and then want to execute some code.
 // ************ code to be executed now is here*************
```

I want to wait for all the async call to complete and then want to execute some code.

Comment: Try making use of the Future api instead of a callback, check this reference:https://dennis-xlc.gitbooks.io/restful-java-with-jax-rs-2-0-2rd-edition/en/part1/chapter13/async_invoker_client_api.html

Comment: Thank you for giving your time and response. Can you please show me how to do this in my code sample. As I am using the loop to call multiple API calls, how can I wait for the response of all the call to complete. I want like, all the 10 calls get initiated, withoute wait for the response of other call, but after this I want to wait for all the 10 call to complete.

Comment: @SariAlalem can you show me, how to do this in my code.